# WordPress - Validate metas and return error message in Gutenberg

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Previously I did this:

```
function my_save_post($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    $errors = new WP_Error('my_errors', 'Something wrong:');
    // if having error
    $errors->add('my_errors', 'some error message');
    //...
    //...
    //...

    if (count($errors->get_error_messages()) > 1) {
        global $wpdb;
        // set the status of the post to **pending** as its metas has some errors.
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array('post_status' => 'pending'), array('ID' => $post->ID));
        set_transient('my_errors', $errors, 10);
    } else {
        // publish the post and update the metas
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'my_save_post', 10, 3);


function my_notices()
{
    if ($errors = get_transient('my_errors')): ?>
        <div class="error">
        <?php foreach ($errors->get_error_messages() as $error): ?>
            <p><?php esc_html_e($error) ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div><?php

        delete_transient('my_errors');
    endif;
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_notices');
```

But now I don't know how I can implement it to validate the data and if there was any error to unpublish the post as it has error and then return some error message in Gutenberg.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very broad. You cannot operate Gutenberg via PHP.
You have to use Javascript (ES6), WordPress version of React and Redux and be familiar with Block editor API. The best starting point is [Block Editor Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/). For a simple use cases, you don't have to know much of React or Redux, but for more complicated cases, it is necessary, at least in my experience. As regards to setting post status to "pending", you should find how to do that via WordPress REST API, and then use `editEntityRecord('postType', 'post', { appropriate rest updates in form field:value }` and use `saveEditedEntityRecord` if you want to save the post before user decides to do so. For notices in Gutenberg, you should use [Notices Component](https://wordpress.github.io/gutenberg/?path=/story/components-notice--default). You did not provide data validation code, but, whatever it is, it should be written in Javascript, and you can use `getEntityRecord` or more dedicated similar functions to get data via the REST to obtain data from the post if you need it.
**EDIT**: I believe [`editPost`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/#editpost) action should be the one to change post attribute to *pending*, however I am not certain, as I have never used it. After all, such specialized actions in the end all resolve to editEntityRecord.